# Read and compare string in a vim (python) script

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to read a string in a python script within vim, but something goes wrong. I do it in a function getting an argument called `key`, using `s = vim.eval("a:key")`, but this is a simpler example demonstrating the problem:

```
:py import vim
:py s = vim.eval("'foo'")
:py print s                      # this prints 'foo' (without the quotes)
:py if s is 'foo': print 'yes'   # this doesn't print 'yes'
```

The problem is that `s is 'foo'` does not evaluate to `True`. My guess is that it has something to do with `vim.eval`, but it's only a guess.

Comment: What's the result when you use

    `:py if s == 'foo': print 'yes'`?

Remember that 'is' tests to see if the objects are the same, so it's looking to see if id(s) is the same as id('foo')

Comment: Omg, I've been reading about the difference between `==` and `is` for the past hour on SO, and I just got it the other way round... Thanks.